# Eloquent query: Retrieving data from two related models having Same column names

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following gives the list of ID's of `SectionDetail` Model while I need List of ID's of `Section` Model:

```
SectionDetail::with('section')->where('class_id', '=', Input::get('grade_id'))->lists('id');
```

Problem is both Models `SectionDetail` and `Section` has columns "ID".

How can I point to the ID of `SectionDetail` and `Section` Model in my Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that this way, since there are 2 separate queries fetching `SectionDetail` and `Section`.
In order to get `Section` ids you need to query that model filtered by the relation constraint:

```
$gradeId = Input::get('grade_id');

// assuming sectionDetails is relation name on the Section model 
$sectionsIds = Section::whereHas('sectionDetails', function ($q) use ($gradeId) {
    $q->where('class_id', '=', $gradeId); // use prefixed column name in case it's ambiguous
})->lists('id');
```